# How to get difference between two dates to get result something like Result as 2 Days, 23 hours, 56 mins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to get difference between two dates in sql server 2012. I am using this select statement. I want result something as

```
select (getdate()-2) - (GetDATE()) as 'Diff'

Result as 2 Days, 23 hours, 56 mins
```

Comment: There is no nice way to do this, do it in your UI layer.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type designed to hold time *spans*. (It has `time`, but that's designed for *times of day*, so e.g. only supports values less than 24 hours). You either compute the value in the smallest units you need and do the maths or, as DavidG says, process this data somewhere else where a richer type system is available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DAT1 datetime = '20160401 13:10:23';
DECLARE @DAT2 datetime = '20160405 12:15:22';


select FLOOR(ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2)) / 24 / 3600) as 'DAYS', 
       FLOOR(ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2)) / 3600) % 24 'HOURS',
       FLOOR(ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2)) / 60) % 60 'MINUTES',
       ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2))  % 60 'SECONDS'
```

in that case

```
    select CAST(FLOOR(ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2)) / 24 / 3600) as nvarchar(10)) + 
        ' DAYS, ' + 
        CAST(FLOOR(ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2)) / 3600) % 24 as nvarchar(2)) +  
        ' HOURS, ' + 
        CAST((ABS(datediff(SECOND, @dat1,@dat2)) / 60) % 60  as nvarchar(2)) + 
        ' MINUTES';
```

Comment: This is working fine but I want result in one cell as concatenated string. So result should be something like `2 Days, 12 Hours, 56 Minutes`